# Проблемы с горизонтальным скролом в WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Есть грида с одной колонкой. Колонка имеет Width="*". Проблема в том, что если содержимое textblock не влезает, горизонтальный скрол не появляется. Если поставить Width="Auto", то скрол появляется, но тогда справа от колонки есть пустое место. А его бы видеть не хотелось

```
<Window x:Class="AFP_GUI.EventFilterPropertyWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AFP_GUI"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:CommonGUI.Controls;assembly=CommonGUI"
            xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:CommonGUI.Controls;assembly=CommonGUI"
    mc:Ignorable="d"                
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"         
    Title="Настройка фильтра"
    MinHeight="300"
    MinWidth="300"
    MaxHeight="800"
    MaxWidth="800"        
    Style="{StaticResource LFWindowStyle}">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:EventFilterPropertyWindowViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding CancelCommand, 
        Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}" 
                Key="Esc"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <cc:ButtonEdit Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}"
                   Text="{Binding NewItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   ButtonImage="/resources/Enter.png"
                   ShowImage="Visible">
        <cc:ButtonEdit.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type cc:ButtonEdit}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type cc:ButtonEdit}}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanAddNewItem}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </cc:ButtonEdit.Style>
    </cc:ButtonEdit>
    
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelItem}" 
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                              VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                              VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
                              IsReadOnly="True"                                  
                              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"                                  
                              SelectionMode="Extended"
                              SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                          PreviewMouseDown="checkBox_PreviewMouseDown"
                                          Margin="5,0,4,0"                                              
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" 
                                           Padding="9,2,2,2" 
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           MinHeight="20">                                       
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>                
            <!--<DataGrid.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Command="{Binding AcceptCommand}" Key="Enter" />
            </DataGrid.InputBindings>-->
        </DataGrid>
    
    <local:OkCancelControl Grid.Row="2"
                           OkCommand="{Binding OkCommand}"
                           CancelCommand="{Binding CancelCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

Может кто знает как полечить. Кидать Гриду на скролвью пытался, не помогает.

Comment: Вот нашел [точно такой же вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4997596/12888024), но очень старый, можете еще поискать на эту же тему.

Comment: Спасибо, сделал, работает

Answer (score 0):

Установите свойство ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" и поместите ваш DataGrid в любой из контейнеров например в Grid, DockPanel, ContentControl или Window у становите ограничение контейнера по Width. Когда содержимое DataGrid  не будет помешаться в родительский контейнер, активируется HorizontalScrollBar.